# List of unique occurrences based on a substring - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of values as follows...

```
Maestro purchase 28.02.2019 18:54 Coop-4853 ZH Bombach Card number: 79090775                
Payment order               
Maestro purchase 27.02.2019 08:29 VBZ FRANKENTAL Card number: 79111775              
Maestro purchase 27.02.2019 17:48 VBZ SIHLQUAI/HB Card number: 79111775             
Maestro purchase 27.02.2019 08:29 VBZ FRANKENTAL Card number: 79111775              
Debit LSV+ VISECA CARD SERVICES SA              
Maestro purchase 27.02.2019 18:36 Coop-4853 ZH Bombach Card number: 79111775                
Maestro purchase 25.02.2019 14:32 VBZ ZURICH VERKEHRSB Card number: 79111776                
Maestro purchase 25.02.2019 16:21 Gemeinde Oberengstri Card number: 79111776                
Maestro purchase 23.02.2019 14:39 VBZ FRANKENTAL Card number: 79111776              
Maestro purchase 23.02.2019 15:27 VBZ MEIERHOFPLATZ Card number: 79111776               
Credit              
Maestro purchase 23.02.2019 15:21 Coop-1906 ZH Höngger Card number: 79111776                
Maestro purchase 22.02.2019 11:12 VBZ FRANKENTAL Card number: 79111776              
Maestro purchase 21.02.2019 07:36 VBZ FRANKENTAL Card number: 79111775
```

I'd like to have one function that returns a **list of all unique occurrences based on this rule**:

> IF the string starts with `Maestro` extract the string in between the first 34 chars and the last 22
>
> `[34 chars] "String to be extracted" [22 chars]`
>
> IF the string does not start with `Maestro`, then get the full string.

I was able to extract the strings based on the rule above with this function `IFERROR(MID(A2,35,LEN(A2)-56),A2)` but somehow I got stuck because I might have to wrap everything in an array formula or something...

If it helps here's a spreadsheet with the data

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPsZSVRMVZDDlYV7MovJ__0hkIMlXHTWg4Eq5_20gxw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, 
 "Maestro purchase \d+.\d+.\d+ \d+:\d+ | Card number: \d+", "")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. This will help others adapt your answer to their own needs. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22357554).